# How to store the API URL root in React js?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to store the API url root in my .env file in react like this `REACT_APP_ROOT_URL=http://localhost:7000` but always return error like in the image [I attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qr3Gj.png)

What did I do wrong? Can anyone tell me what is the correct way to store the API url root in env file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the info you shared there can be multiple reasons. Can you please share the code for the file importing and using the variable ?

Comment: Everytime you change the .env file. You need to restart your server.